# How to slice a String object until it reaches "/" mark?

Tags: javascript, string, url

I have a link `"http://client.local/#/wiki/revision/new/1"` and I'd like to slice off everything of it and leave only the `id` (`"1"` in the example). Now I know that can be done using JavaScript's `slice()` function, but it must slice it from the end until it reaches the `/` sign no matter how many letters the id contains.

How can I do that?

Comment: Is the ID the number `1`?

Comment: What part is the id? /1?

Comment: In the given example, the `ID` is `1`, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regex :

```
var id = url.match(/[^\/]*$/)[0];
```

or split :

```
var id = url.split('/').pop();
```

Using a regex allows for better easy control. For example if you want to fail if what follows the last `/` isn't made of digits, do

```
var m = url.match(/\/(\d+)$/)
if (m) {
    var id = m[1];
    ...
} else {
    // bad URL, let's handle the error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another variant

```
var id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `split` and not `slice`

```
var id = "http://client.local/#/wiki/revision/new/1234".split('/').pop();
```

Comment: Doesn't your answer suggest that it will leave the `id` only if it's a single character long?

Comment: No, the split function splits string st at each '/' and the id will be everything after last '/'

Answer (score 0):

Given that javascript regular expressions are greedy by default, you can do:

```
var id = url.replace(/.*\//,'');
```

which will return everything after the last '/'.